# the same class provided in different packages?

Tags: android

I was searching for the android documentation for `AppBarLayout`, I found that there are more than one packages with the same class. e.g. `AppBarLayout` was defined in the `android.support.design.widget` package and it was also defined in the `com.google.android.material.appbar` package.

So, I wanted to see if any differences existed with the `AppBarLayout`s of the two different packages, but, it seems to me that they are 100% identical. So, I'm not quite sure why is the same things provided in two different packages and how do we know for sure these are the same thing for sure(like if any reference is given anywhere where the same thing is included in other packages as well)?

Comment: `com.google.android.material.appbar` is mostly from github samples or customized one, please ignore this import. `android.support.design.widget` is the actual package shipped with android sdk support library.

Comment: @silentsudo , and why isn't including the library from the project structure tab as a dependency not let android studio detect this?

Comment: Because it is `Android Studio`, I would encourage you to search maven repo find specific gradle and add manually in build.gradle file, if problem still persists

Comment: @silentsudo, what do you mean? Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @silentsudo , I've been seeing and asking around and this website: [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) mentioned in my this question: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103358/adding-the-design-support-library/58105557?noredirect=1#comment102649838_58105557) somehow suggests using it