# adding the design support library

Tags: java, android, linux

I use android studio 3.5, and the only way I've found through searching to add a library is via the `project structure` in android studio or directly downloading a `.jar` and adding it manually. I've done the former, for the `android.support.design` library but, android studio doesn't detect it and the `project structure` lists more than one result for the same library. I'm utterly confused to how these work, I went to **search.maven.org** to see if I could find a `.jar` but I didn't, there were no search results.

Please tell me how do I add this library to my project(if possible without downloading the `.jar` but a link to the `.jar` would be helpful) and let `Android studio` detect it.

Also, my compile SDK version is 29, target SDK is 29, min SDK is 19, and I'm on linux OS.

Comment: Downloang .jar files can be automatically done by gradle. No need for manual work if the .jar files exist in repositories like jCenter or Google's maven

Comment: @Crazo7924 , where do these downloaded libraries go once grade automatically downloads it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available in Build > Edit Libraries and Dependencies (see the top bar).

Have a look at this -> https://images.app.goo.gl/STfMX9zTy3ZMQG7r5

Comment: please have a look at this: https://ibb.co/sHB90Cc , this method somehow doesn't work and I have mentioned it in my question itself. It is same as accessing the libraries from the project structure tab

Comment: @juztcode The design library is now called materialcomponents. Read more about it here -> https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started

Comment: and what does it mean by Google's maven repository, isn't maven a separate repository apart from google, or google owns it?

Comment: Google has its own maven repo. Check this link to just have a look at what it has -> https://maven.google.com

Comment: how do we know the compatibility of the library and the SDK?

Comment: Try adding the library to check the min SDK. The current minimum requirement is API 14 for AndroidX which is Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich (see just above this -> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library#uses)

Comment: can we not download the support library as a .jar?

Comment: Target SDK >= Minimum SDK always. From what I can see your min. SDK is 19 and target is 28. The condition for the support library is satisfied.

Comment: if the conditions are satisfied, I wonder why the import doesn't work? Do you have any hints?

Comment: Build > Clean Project  should help. Also do Invalidate caches (search for this. I'm not sitting in front of the computer right now). Restart the Android Studio then try again.